# htaccess URL rewrite: What am I messing up in the code?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have the following rewrite rule:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} Catalog\/(string|page)\/
RewriteRule ^Catalog\/(string|page)\/([^\/]+)\/[^\.]+\.html$  Catalog/Catalog.php?$1=$2
```

RewriteRule is on one line but may be showing on multiple lines here.

My questions is mainly what am I doing wrong. I am not getting any errors so Rewrite is working. The address I am typing in to the browser is `www.domain.com/Catalog/string/RT/Round_Tomato.html` and what I was hoping to get is `www.domain.com/Catalog/Catalog.php?string=RT`

I am guessing my regex is messed up but have not been able to get it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the first wrong thing is putting point without backslash before (.) => www.

```
 ^www\.([^/])/Catalog/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+).html$ www.$1/Catalog/Catalog.php?string=$2
```

here is a clear example:

> RewriteRule   ^http://www.remotesite.com/(.*)$
>   /mirror/of/remotesite/$1

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

check this out:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^Catalog/(.+)/(.+)\.html$ /Catalog/Catalog.php?$1=$2
```

you should restart your apache server -if it's a local server- (start and stop) and you must be able to access http://localhost/Catalog/string/RT.html

Comment: Geez I didnt even check the uploaded comment. I have the backslash in there but it seems the stackoverflow uses it as an escape. I am going to update so the code shows correctly. Thanks for the catch and also good read, better than what I was finding through Google.

Comment: did this solved your problem or I must search for more mistakes?

Comment: Not as of yet but I am going to read through that tut you gave me and see if I can find any more mistakes then post back.

Comment: ok...I wait for your reply, If you can't fix it after reading the tut let me know

Comment: Nope still not getting any rewrites. I am beginning to wonder if a server setting is just not working for this Rule in particular because much simpler rewrites are working.

Comment: This is workign with a bit of a modification. For some reason the base directory was not taking but after I started using /New/Catalog/string/RT/Round_Tomatoe.html this is working fine. I realize that this part of the site is in the New directory but I still dont understand why that was not being used as the base. Oh well. Thanks again.

Comment: ok. You know.. if I were at your computer maybe the problem would have been resolved faster:). It's good that you managed to get it work. Keep it on